# Java send nullbyte (\x00) as 1 character using AsynchronousSocketChannel

Tags: java

I need to send nullbyte as 1 character this code send its as 4 characters so not a nullbyte (\x00) , it can't be sending it as plain text. it's sending to a flash client. I'm using AsynchronousSocketChannel to send the packets.
the nullbyte is to tell the server that the packet has ended.
for example when I send test\x00 it sends it as test\x00 which is wrong.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
import java.net.SocketAddress;

import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.channels.AsynchronousSocketChannel;
import java.nio.channels.CompletionHandler;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;

import java.util.concurrent.Future;

public class Main {



    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String connect = "gfdg";
        System.out.println(connect);

        String request = connect;
        AsynchronousSocketChannel channel = AsynchronousSocketChannel.open();
        SocketAddress serverAddr = new InetSocketAddress("artix.aqw.aq.com", 5588);
        Future<Void> result = channel.connect(serverAddr);
        result.get();
        Attachment attach = new Attachment();
        attach.channel = channel;
        attach.buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(2048);
        attach.isRead = false;
        attach.mainThread = Thread.currentThread();

        Charset cs = Charset.forName("UTF-8");
        String msg = request;
        byte[] data = msg.getBytes(cs);
        attach.buffer.put(data);
        attach.buffer.flip();

        ReadWriteHandler readWriteHandler = new ReadWriteHandler();
        channel.write(attach.buffer, attach, readWriteHandler);
        attach.mainThread.join();
    }
}

class Attachment {
    AsynchronousSocketChannel channel;
    ByteBuffer buffer;
    Thread mainThread;
    boolean isRead;
}

class ReadWriteHandler implements CompletionHandler<Integer, Attachment> {

    @Override
    public void completed(Integer result, Attachment attach) {
        if (attach.isRead) {
            attach.buffer.flip();
            Charset cs = Charset.forName("UTF-8");
            int limits = attach.buffer.limit();
            byte bytes[] = new byte[limits];
            attach.buffer.get(bytes, 0, limits);
            String msg = new String(bytes, cs);
            String str = new String(bytes,cs).split("\0")[0];

            System.out.format("Server Responded: " + str + "\n");
            try {
                msg = this.getTextFromUser();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            if (msg.equalsIgnoreCase("bye")) {
                attach.mainThread.interrupt();
                return;
            }
            attach.buffer.clear();
            byte[] data = msg.getBytes(cs);
            attach.buffer.put(data);
            attach.buffer.flip();
            attach.isRead = false; // It is a write
            attach.channel.write(attach.buffer, attach, this);
        } else {
            attach.isRead = true;
            attach.buffer.clear();
            attach.channel.read(attach.buffer, attach, this);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void failed(Throwable e, Attachment attach) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    private String getTextFromUser() throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Please enter a  message:");
        BufferedReader consoleReader = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(System.in));

        String msg = consoleReader.readLine() + "\\x00";
        return msg;
    }


}
```

Comment: A Java character is 16-bits. `'\0'` is not a `byte`.

Comment: Write your string without this null-char suffix, then call `ByteBuffer.put​((byte) 0)` to append a single null byte

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should write a single null byte (`0x00`) after writing your string to the channel. What you're doing is not it: you're appending the string `\x00` instead (a backslash followed by an x and two 0s).

Against my first instincts, it seems it will work if you append the unicode character `\u0000` to your string, but the optimal way to do it is simply to put a `byte` with value `0` into the `ByteBuffer` after putting your string.

*To be clear, I expected the null byte to be doubled when you append `\u0000`, as Java encodes chars as UTF-16, hence on 2 bytes. But we're explicitly encoding the String to UTF-8 to get it as bytes, so the null char is indeed encoded as a single null byte.*

Here's a small demo of this, showing for each method the length of data written to the channel, then its value as bytes:

```java
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.channels.Channels;
import java.nio.channels.WritableByteChannel;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Buffer {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        try (Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in)) {

            boolean done = false;
            while(!done) {

                System.out.println("Enter string to encode, 'bye' to exit:");

                String s = scan.nextLine();
                if ("bye".equals(s.toLowerCase())) {
                    done = true;
                    break;
                }

                System.out.println("withNullChar");
                String withNullChar = s + '\u0000';
                ByteBuffer buff = ByteBuffer.allocate(1024);
                buff.put(withNullChar.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
                System.out.println("Length: " + buff.position());
                buff.flip();
                byte[] result = readBack(buff);
                printArray(result);

                System.out.println("withNullCharFaulty");
                String withNullCharFaulty = s + "\\x00";
                buff = ByteBuffer.allocate(1024);
                buff.put(withNullCharFaulty.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
                System.out.println("Length: " + buff.position());
                buff.flip();
                result = readBack(buff);
                printArray(result);

                System.out.println("with null byte");
                buff = ByteBuffer.allocate(1024);
                buff.put(s.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)).put((byte) 0);
                System.out.println("Length: " + buff.position());
                buff.flip();
                result = readBack(buff);
                printArray(result);

            }

        }

    }

    public static byte[] readBack(ByteBuffer buff) throws IOException {
        try (ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream()) {
            try (WritableByteChannel channel = Channels.newChannel(bos)) {
                channel.write(buff);
                return bos.toByteArray();
            }
        }
    }

    public static void printArray(byte[] arr) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (byte b : arr)
            sb.append(String.format("%02X ", b));
        System.out.println(sb);
    }

}
```